# Can I get the video preview for the videos on a website?

Tags: php, html, video

I am creating a site which displays videos like youtube. The only problem I am facing is getting the thumbnails for the videos. I don't want to upload the thumbnails, but instead want an automatic thumbnail and the short preview on hover just like youtube. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
   <?php
      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'scorpio');
      $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM video");
      ?>
   <?php
      foreach($query as $sl):
      ?>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="speaker">
         <a href="videoplayback.php?id=<?php echo $sl['v_id']; ?>">
            <video src="media/<?php echo $sl['video_name']; ?>" class="img-fluid">
               <div class="details">
                  <h3>
         <a href="videoplayback.php?id=<?php echo $sl['v_id']; ?>"><?php echo $sl['url']; ?></a></h3>
         </div>
         </video>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php endforeach;  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to start on your own and come back with a specific question. Your question is more or less that we should develop most of your page. That is not what SO is for

Comment: I have developed all of the site, I am only facing issues with the thumbnails for the video

Comment: you will need to generate thumbnails either at upload or as a batch job and then create a display mechanism. I'd use something like plyr.io for playback and create the sprite sheet via server side ffmpeg for each video on upload

Answer (score -1):

When the user uploads the video you should generate the **thumbnail** in one of your directories , same goes with your preview and save it somewhere.

Comment: that is the problem. i cannot figure out how to do that

Comment: check out this link https://github.com/emgag/video-thumbnail-sprite